# Python can't find tkinter item at coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse-coordinates

I have this code:

```python
for item in items:
    print ( "Item: ", item, mycanvas.coords (item) )

print ("Item at 26.0, 188.0 ", mycanvas.find_closest(26.0, 188.0))
print ("Item at 998.0, 594.0 ", mycanvas.find_closest(998.0, 594.0))
```

When I run it I get:

```python
('Item: ', 1, [985.0, 565.0])
('Item: ', 8, [25.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 15, [505.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 28, [1362.0, 31.0])
('Item: ', 35, [1020.0, 119.0])
('Item: ', 42, [1050.0, 583.0])
('Item: ', 49, [25.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 56, [26.0, 188.0])
('Item: ', 63, [998.0, 594.0])
('Item: ', 70, [1152.0, 38.0])
('Item at 26.0, 188.0 ', (57,))
('Item at 998.0, 594.0 ', (64,))
```

The last two lines should read items `56` and `63` found, respectively.

I have 10 images on the screen and am trying to find out which one is being clicked on.  To make matters worse X, Y coordinates are being passed for the screen position and not the canvas position and I'll have to figure out how to convert:

```python
def popup(event):
    x = mycanvas.canvasx(event.x_root)
    y = mycanvas.canvasy(event.y_root)
    print( "Adjusted x, y: ", x, y )
    FoundItem=mycanvas.find_closest(x, y)
    print( "Found Item @ x, y: ", FoundItem, event.x_root, event.y_root )
    FoundTuple=mycanvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x+1, y+1)
    print( "Found Tuple: ", FoundTuple )
    # use coordinates relative to the canvas
#    ItemNdx=items.index(FoundItem)
#    print( "ItemNdx: ", ItemNdx )
    menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

In Python's Tkinter what's the easiest way to find out which image (item/ tag ID) a user has clicked on?

---

### Monitor image with Window Images

To give an idea of what the canvas looks like:

[image: wman2 edp-1-1.png]

This is the portion for one of the three monitors eDP-1-1. Giving worst case scenario there are four windows open:

- `gedit` with this source code in question open on bottom.
- Firefox browser with this Q&A open above that.
- Nautilus windows above that.
- Gnome-terminal on the top.

Window stacking order isn't perfect yet because `wmctrl` is used to get all open windows on desktop without any sorting by stacking order yet.

So the user would click closest to the top left corner of the image they want to select. User could also click empty monitor area not covered by a window to select the monitor image.
- Firefox browser with this website

### Tag current is also one off

I put in this code:

```python
tag_current=event.widget.find_withtag("current")
print ("tag_current: ", tag_current)
```

And the results were this:

```python
('Item: ', 1, [985.0, 565.0])
('Item: ', 8, [25.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 15, [505.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 28, [1362.0, 31.0])
('Item: ', 35, [949.0, 167.0])
('Item: ', 42, [1050.0, 583.0])
('Item: ', 49, [83.0, 52.0])
('Item: ', 56, [26.0, 188.0])
('Item: ', 63, [998.0, 594.0])
('Item: ', 70, [25.0, 25.0])
('Item: ', 77, [1091.0, 644.0])
('Item at 26.0, 188.0 ', (70,))
('Item at 998.0, 594.0 ', (64,))
('tag_current: ', (41,))
```

`tag_current` should be `42` but is being reported as `41`.

Much the same problem where `63` is reported as `64` and `56` is being reported as `70` (previously reported as `57` last time job was run).

---

### 12 hour update

12 hours later and I'm getting closer. It is necessary to convert from Window coordinates (entire desktop of three monitors) to canvas coordinates (one Python program on one of the monitors):

```python
def popup(event):
    global FoundItem, MouseXY
    x = mycanvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = mycanvas.canvasy(event.y)
    MouseXY=(x, y)
    print( "Adjusted x, y: ", x, y )
    FoundItem=mycanvas.find_closest(x, y)
```

Hopefully by tonight problem will be solved...

Comment: 1) Assign a tag to all image items, e.g. `img = mycanvas.create_image(..., tag='image')`; 2) bind the mouse click event to those image items, e.g. `mycanvas.tag_bind('image', '<Button-1>', on_image_click)`; 3) get the clicked image in `on_image_click()` function using `mycanvas.find_withtag('current')`.

Comment: @acw1668 The image is an open window on the desktop. The number of images is limitless so it hard coding tags with infinite "on_image_click` statements is impossible.

Comment: The image is not an open window on the desktop, it is a canvas image item put at the position of the open window.  So you need to call `mycanvas.create_image(...)` to create the image item, just add `tag='whatever'` in the `mycanvas.create_image(...)` statement.

Comment: @acw1668 My canvas contains 10 images: 3 monitors (HDMI-1, DP-1-1 and eDP-1-1 obtained with screenshot) and 7 windows obtained with `wmctrl -lG`. The Items list is populated with `item=mycanvas.create.image(...)` followed by `items.append( [item] )` I will try a new program version with tags set to `xrandr` monitor name and `wmctrl` Window number in next couple days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution to make it work:

```
def popup(event):
    global FoundItem
#    print( "Root x, y: ", event.x_root, event.y_root )
#    print( "event x, y: ", event.x, event.y )
    FoundItem=mycanvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

You can remove the comments (`#` character) to see the `x,y` coordinates in your terminal.

- The `.tk_popup` or `.post` command expects Screen Desktop coordinates: `(event.x_root, event.y_root)`
- The `.find_closest` command expects Canvas coordinates: `(event.x, event.y)`

Answer (score 1):

The way to find out *"which image (tag/ tag ID) a user has clicked on"* is to use the tag **current**. The canonical tcl/tk documentation says the following about the **current** tag:

> The tag **current** is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the
>   *current item*, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in
>   varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details).
>   If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then
>   no item has the current tag.

Here is a contrived example that will print out the tags associated with whatever item you clicked on. Notice that it works even if you scroll the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    tags = canvas.itemcget("current", "tags")
    label.configure(text=f"you clicked on {tags}")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
label = tk.Label(root)
ysb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set, xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
label.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

x = 10
y = 10
for color in ("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black", "bisque"):
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+100, y+100,
                            outline=color, fill=color,
                            tags=(color,)
    )
    x += 50
    y += 50
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: They might be clicking on the window image under the window image on top. Hard to put into words so I'll update question with an image of the images (windows) on the monitor (also an image)..

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I don't understand your comment. It's impossible to click under a pixel. When you click, the mouse will be over a single pixel. Whatever image drew that pixel is what **current** will return. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that creates several images (or simpler, rectangles).

Comment: `event.widget.find_withtag("current")` also returns the item number 1 off as if the item number for the rectangle around the image was being returned instead of the image item number? As far as code can I simply post the whole thing? Not sure how to slice and dice it into a dumbed down version. The code is in Linux if that matters?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: you don't need to call `find_withtag("current")` - you can direclty use `"current"` anywhere you would use an object id. Note: if you draw a rectangle around an image and then click on the rectangle, **current** will represent the rectangle.

Comment: In an earlier version of the program when I resized the canvas the image wouldn't resize but the rectangle around the image (which I didn't hard code) would resize. Which makes me think tkinter keeps an item number for the image and a separate item number for the rectangle around the image that it was resizing. Note I would have preferred to use just a rectangle to represent a Window on the desktop but alpha channel (for transparency) is only available with an PhotoImage.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: _"Which makes me think tkinter keeps an item number for the image and a separate item number for the rectangle around the image that it was resizing."_ - yes. Every canvas item gets a unique identifier. Though, you can give them both the same tag if you wish.

Comment: Note all items are tagged `all` for resizeable canvas. Instead of "rectangle" I should have said "image border / outline" was resizing but not the RGBA image channels within. Images don't resize and  have to be regenerated with ImagePhoto at each window resize event. Because windows overlap and because rectangles don't have alpha channel I had to use RGBA images pretending to be RGB rectangles. Also I discovered part of my problem was using `event.x_root` and event.y_root` coordinates instead of `event.x` and `event.y` coordinates for looking up item by closest coordinates. +1 though for work.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: _" Images don't resize and have to be regenerated with ImagePhoto at each window resize event."_ - correct. The canvas won't automatically resize images. That's unrelated to the question being asked, however. The question is about finding the item under the cursor. And for that, the tag **current** will always return the item under the cursor with the highest z-order, as my example illustrates.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: you wrote _"Note all items are tagged all for resizeable canvas."_ - Your wording is unclear. By default, items are _not_ "tagged all".  You can use "all" to reference all items, but the items don't actually have that tag.

Comment: Rather than accepting your answer I upvoted two of your most popular answers. Thank you for your time and consideration it is really appreciated from a new learner.